# Pandas - remove cells based on value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with z-scores for several values. It looks like this:

```
ID    Cat1     Cat2     Cat3
A     1.05     -1.67    0.94
B     -0.88    0.22     -0.56
C     1.33     0.84     1.19
```

I want to write a script that will tell me which IDs correspond with values in each category relative to a cut-off value I specify as needed. Because I am working with z-scores, I will need to compare the absolute value against my cut-off.

So if I set my cut-off at 0.75, the resulting dataframe would be:

```
Cat1    Cat2    Cat3
A       A       A
B       C       C
C
```

If I set 1.0 as my cut-off value: the dataframe above would return:

```
Cat1    Cat2    Cat3
A       A       C
C
```

I know that I can do queries like this:

```
df1 = df[df['Cat1'] > 1]
df1
df1 = df[df['Cat1'] < -1]
df1
```

to individually query each column and find the information I'm looking for but this is tedious even if I figure out how to use the abs function to combine the two queries into one.How can I apply this filtration to the whole dataframe?

I've come up with this skeleton of a script:

```
cut_off = 1.0
cols = list(df.columns)
cols.remove('ID')
for col in cols:
    # FOR CELL IN VALUE OF EACH CELL IN COLUMN:
        if (abs.CELL < cut_off):
            CELL = NaN
```

to basically just eliminate any values that don't meet the cut-off. If I can get this to work, it will bring me closer to my goal but I am stuck and don't even know if I am on the right track. Again, the overall goal is to quickly figure out which cells have absolute-values above the cut-off in each category be able to list the corresponding IDs.

I apologize if anything is confusing or vague; let me know in comments and I'll fix it. I've been trying to figure this out for most of today and my brain is somewhat fried

Comment: Not sure if this is close enough `df.apply(lambda x: x.index)[abs(df) > 1]`

Comment: This returned an error: TypeError: bad operand type for abs(): 'unicode'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to apply the filtration to columns, you can also do

```
df[df > 1]
```

, and also,

```
df[df > 1] = np.NaN
```